# missing keyword error in oracle CASE WHEN sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, procedure, case-when

I am writing a procedure in which i have sql statement which will insert values in `TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW` table using `CASE WHEN` statement. The condition is when `STATUS_ID` is `0` then the `EVENT_ID=10003` and when `STATUS_ID` is `1` then `EVETN_ID=10018`. When i try to use `CASE WHEN` for this its giving me error missing keyword.I dont know but is there any other way to do this if not using `CASE WHEN` statement. I am thinking about using `cursor` but dont know how to do this.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ext_self_10003_sigwf AS BEGIN       
    -- first empty TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW';

    -- get WF_WORKFLOW table data 
    INSERT INTO temp_wf_workflow (status_id, event_id, order_number)
      SELECT
        wf.status_id,
        CASE WHEN wf.status_id = 0 THEN event_id = 10003
        WHEN wf.status_id = 1 THEN event_id = 10018 END AS eventid,
        tsm.order_number 
       FROM wf_workflow@fonic_retail wf
        JOIN tmp_soap_monitoring_ids tsm ON tsm.subscription_id = wf.subscription_id
       WHERE tsm.order_type = 'SELF_REGISTRATION' AND wf.name = 'SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID';

    COMMIT;

  END ext_self_10003_sigwf;
```

Comment: You have CASE syntax mix. Either CASE WHEN c = val THEN..., or CASE var WHEN val THEN...

Comment: You have mixed two different case syntax. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  CASE EVENT_ID WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0 THEN EVENT_ID=10003 
>     WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1 THEN EVENT_ID=10018 END AS EVENTID
> ```

You have mixed two different **syntax** of **CASE** statement.

**1.simple_case_statement**

```
   CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

   END
```

**2.searched_case_statement**

```
CASE 

   WHEN expression condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN expression condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN expression condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Change your expression to -

```
CASE 
   WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0 THEN 10003 
   WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1 THEN 10018
END AS EVENTID
```

Follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/case_statement.htm#LNPLS01304) to see the documentation for both the syntax.

**Update** OP says he still gets the **missing keyword error**. This is a test case to show it is not true. The missing keyword will be fixed with correct CASE statement.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE EXT_SELF_10003_SIGWF
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5    -- first empty TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW table
  6    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW';
  7    -- get WF_WORKFLOW table data
  8    INSERT
  9    INTO TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW
 10      (
 11        STATUS_ID,
 12        EVENT_ID,
 13        ORDER_NUMBER
 14      )
 15    SELECT WF.STATUS_ID,
 16      CASE
 17        WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0
 18        THEN 10003
 19        WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1
 20        THEN 10018
 21      END AS EVENTID,
 22      TSM.ORDER_NUMBER
 23    FROM WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF
 24    JOIN TMP_SOAP_MONITORING_IDS TSM
 25    ON TSM.SUBSCRIPTION_ID=WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
 26    WHERE TSM.order_type  ='SELF_REGISTRATION'
 27    AND WF.NAME           ='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID';
 28    COMMIT;
 29  END EXT_SELF_10003_SIGWF;
 30  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for PROCEDURE EXT_SELF_10003_SIGWF:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------
7/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
23/8     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL>
```

Comment: Please check the edited question as per ur answer i tried but again the same error :( missing keyword

Comment: Ohh now i undestood my mistake. Its working fine now :) Thank you Lalit :) Just a small error not able to identify properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a test case though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

insert in THEN only value

```
CASE WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0 THEN 10003 
WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1 THEN 10018 END
```

Comment: Please take a look on Oracle CASE syntax (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) and review your code. Now it is not correct.

Comment: No same error again missing keyword. I have checked that documentation previously but did not find any idea.

Comment: What a crappy reference on "techonthenet": It's a case *expression*, not a case *statement*. And they seem clueless as to the distinction between PL/SQL and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `EVENT_ID` from within the `CASE`:

```
...
CASE -- EVENT_ID
   WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0 THEN 10003 
   WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1 THEN 10018
END AS EVENTID
...
```

CASE takes two forms:

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <value> -- etc
    ELSE <default value> -- optional
END
```

Or

```
CASE <value source>
    WHEN <match value> THEN <result value>
    WHEN <match value> THEN <result value> -- etc
    ELSE <default value> -- optional
END
```

Comment: @Rahul I did have an error briefly (check it again). I'm pretty sure it will work

Comment: Please check the edited question as per ur answer i tried but again the same error :( missing keyword

Answer (score 1):

Case statement is implemented incorrectly. You can use case in two ways:
1)

```
Case <some_variable or column_name> 
  When <value1> then <return_value>
else
  <return_value>
end;
```

2)

```
    Case 
      When <logical_stamtement (e.g. value1=0 or column1=0)> then <return_value>
    else
      <return_value>
    end
```

In your program you have used both of them simultaneously. Correct code should be

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EXT_SELF_10003_SIGWF AS 

    BEGIN

    -- first empty TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW'; 


    -- get WF_WORKFLOW table data 
    Insert into TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW(STATUS_ID,EVENT_ID,ORDER_NUMBER)
    Select WF.STATUS_ID,
    CASE WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=0 THEN 10003 
    WHEN WF.STATUS_ID=1 THEN 10018 END AS EVENTID
    ,TSM.ORDER_NUMBER FROM WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF 
    where WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID';

    commit;

    END EXT_SELF_10003_SIGWF;
```

Comment: Please check the edited question as per ur answer i tried but again the same error :( missing keyword